# Concat single column values without supporting column(ex:- ID) in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a single column

```
Value
A
B
C
NULL
NULL
F
R
D
NULL
T
R
NULL
```

Expected Output:

```
value
ABC
FRD
TR
```

Aim is to group column values until next NULL and so on..

```
CREATE TABLE DUMMY1(VALUE VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO DUMMY1(VALUE) VALUES('A')
INSERT INTO DUMMY1(VALUE) VALUES('B')
INSERT INTO DUMMY1(VALUE) VALUES('C')
INSERT INTO DUMMY1(VALUE) VALUES(NULL)
INSERT INTO DUMMY1(VALUE) VALUES(NULL)
INSERT INTO DUMMY1(VALUE) VALUES('F')
INSERT INTO DUMMY1(VALUE) VALUES('R')
INSERT INTO DUMMY1(VALUE) VALUES('D')
INSERT INTO DUMMY1(VALUE) VALUES(NULL)
INSERT INTO DUMMY1(VALUE) VALUES('T')
INSERT INTO DUMMY1(VALUE) VALUES('R')
INSERT INTO DUMMY1(VALUE) VALUES(NULL)
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Comment: Tables in a relational database represent **unordered** sets. Unless you have a column that defines a sort order, there is no such thing as "until next".

Comment: Perhaps a little explanation around what the use case for this question is may help too, as based on what you’ve asked, I think a tool like Excel may be better for it and can quite easily be achieved.

Answer (score 1):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  Your question makes no sense, unless I assume that that rows are ordered.  This requires a separate column for the ordering.

Let me assume that you have such a column, which I will call `id`.  Then, you can use a cumulative count to assign the groups and then aggregate:

```
SELECT STRING_AGG(value, '') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY id)
FROM (SELECT d.*,
             SUM(CASE WHEN VALUE IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (ORDER BY id) as grp
      FROM DUMMY1 d
     ) d
WHERE value IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY grp;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=302a2ed5ca7a9fa3a6cafd6644319593) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below:

```
SELECT value from STRING_SPLIT
(
    (select SUBSTRING( 
                    ( 
                            SELECT ''+ isnull(Value,',')
                                FROM DUMMY1
                                FOR XML PATH('') 
             
                    ), 1 , 9999)), 
',') as SS
where SS.value <> ''
```